# Python installing twarc using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

i'm new to coding and hoping to get some advice. I am using macOs Big Sur Version 11.4
I am trying to install a package called twarc and ran the following within my terminal.
`pip install twarc`
when I run `pip show twarc`
I see the following:

```
**Name: twarc
Version: 2.1.2
Summary: Archive tweets from the command line
Home-page: https://github.com/docnow/twarc
Author: Ed Summers
Author-email: ehs@pobox.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/cominocomputer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: click, click-config-file, requests-oauthlib, click-plugins, python-dateutil
Required-by:**
```

whenever I run `pip2 show twarc` I see the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip2')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

What I assume to be the error is that I have Python2 and Python3 installed. I also have pip2 and pip3. Twarc got installed into pip3 but is not working properly when I try to run a python file because perhaps my file is running on pip2?

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
I have tried `pip2 install typing` this does not resolve the issue.
Below is an image of the error i get in IDLE when trying to use "import twarc" within my .py
[image]

Comment: Use python3. Probably by typing python3 at the command prompt.

Comment: You should be using virtual environments to solve problems like this. Conda is robust and easy to use/install. I highly recommend. [Instructions here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). There's a learning curve for using any virtual environments, but it's far shorter/faster than dealing with you base python environment getting all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

based on you module name in python registry name is `[twarc][https://pypi.org/project/twarc/2.1.2/]`
you should do `pip install twarc==2.1.2`

Comment: Thank you, I ran this command within my terminal and it said requirement already satisfied. Strange because it works in the terminal, but it doesn't work when i run the python file and check the idle shell.

Comment: so check your file name, file name can't same like your library, it will make a circular import